# Regex for selecting two types of ID

Tags: sql, sql-like

In a table I have an ID field that may vary e.g.

ID

- 4.01.03.137
- 0.000.00.3562

Note that the second level could have two or three digits depending on the type of product. I have tried make a query to split that table in two tables, one containing just data with two digits and another one with the three digits data, but I was unable to succeed using regex.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for two  digits

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable
WHERE ID LIKE '%.[0-9][0-9].%.%'
```

for three digits

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable
WHERE ID LIKE '%.[0-9][0-9][0-9].%.%'
```

Comment: Work flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: This solution is highly specific to SQL Server and the question doesn't specify the database.